# Calculating time depending on string variable in other column

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I have a large data set which contains a time column and a column with the identification of a saccade or fixation of the eye  (saccade = fast eye movement, fixation = relative stable eye movement). I want to calculate how long each period of fixations and saccades last, by taking the time at the start of the first "f" until the first "s" and so on. So if there are 3 consecutive rows with "s", I want it to take the time in column [i] where the first "s" appeared and the time in column [i] where the last "s" appeared before the next "f". By distracting these 2 times I know the duration of each fixation and saccade period.

The time scale is not continuous, since sometimes rows are deleted because of blinks in the data.

```
example.df <- data.frame(time = seq(1:100), 
                         saccade = sample(letters[c(6, 19)], 100, replace = T))
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create an index using `rle()` and then `group_by()` this index to `sum()` the `time`:

```
library(tidyverse)

example.df <- data.frame(time = seq(1:100), 
                         saccade = sample(letters[c(6, 19)], 100, replace = T))

test <- rle(example.df$saccade == "s")

example.df$indexer <- rep(1:length(test$lengths), test$lengths)

example.df <- example.df %>%
  group_by(indexer) %>%
  mutate(period = time[n()] - time[1])

# A tibble: 100 x 4
# Groups:   indexer [53]
    time saccade indexer period
   <int>  <fctr>   <int>  <int>
 1     1       s       1      1
 2     2       s       1      1
 3     3       f       2      0
 4     4       s       3      0
 5     5       f       4      3
 6     6       f       4      3
 7     7       f       4      3
 8     8       f       4      3
 9     9       s       5      1
10    10       s       5      1
# ... with 90 more rows

# drop indexer column
example.df <- example.df[setdiff(names(example.df),"indexer")]
```

Comment: Hi @LAP, this almost does the trick. However, the real timeline does look like this: 275563 275566 275571 275573. I dont want to know the summation of those times, but the time between the first time the "s" appeared and the last time. In this example  10 ms. Any idea how ?

Comment: @BartR I've edited the code, is this what you need? Or would you need anything else than `0` for times with only one row of a status?

Comment: I get the following error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument ".data" is missing, with no default. when running the last part. When there is only one row with a status, 0 is fine! So i do believe that you have my solution here

Comment: Oops, I screwed up the code by copy/pasting. Try again please.

Comment: wow @LAP You are amazing. This does exactly what I want. What an extremely helpfull community on here. Reps to you and krads!! I still dont fully understand why and how it works, but i will figure that out right now.

Comment: It is relatively simple. We use the run length encoding (shows the lengths of consecutive occurences of `'s'` and `not 's'`) to generate a new indexing variable with different values for each sequence. Then we group the data by this variable to calculate the difference between the last value of the sequence `time[n()]` and the first `time[1]`. I've added another row to drop the indexing variable afterwards. Glad I could help.

Comment: Hi @LAP, I found out that there is one small mistake in  "mutate(duration = (Iview[n()] - Iview[1])/1000)", instead of taking the nth, i would like to take the n+1 - [1] so; Iview[n+1]-Iview[1]. However, it doesnt allow it this way. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Result as a data.frame:

```
example.df <- data.frame(time = seq(1:100), 
                         saccade = sample(letters[c(6, 19)], 100, replace = T),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
run_len_encoding <- rle(example.df$saccade)
length_of_runs <- run_len_encoding$length
index_of_changes <- cumsum(length_of_runs)
duration <- diff(c(1,index_of_changes),1)
result.df <- data.frame(duration, state = run_len_encoding$values)
result.df

   duration   state
1         1       s
2         2       f
3         1       s
4         4       f
5         1       s
6         3       f
7         3       s
8         2       f
9         3       s
10        1       f
11        2       s
12        1       f
13        1       s
14        2       f
15        4       s
16        1       f
17        2       s
18        1       f
19        1       s
20        1       f
21        1       s
22        1       f
23        2       s
24        1       f
25        2       s
26        3       f
27        1       s
28        1       f
29        2       s
30        1       f
31        1       s
32        1       f
33        6       s
34        1       f
35        3       s
36        3       f
37        1       s
38        2       f
39        2       s
40        4       f
41        1       s
42        1       f
43        1       s
44        1       f
45        1       s
46        2       f
47        1       s
48        3       f
49        2       s
50        1       f
51        4       s
52        1       f
53        1       s
54        1       f
55        2       s
```

Comment: I added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to the creation of the example df to prevent saccade from becoming a factor.  If you prefer saccade to be left as factor in your df please let me know and I will edit to deal with that in my answer in another way.

Comment: Hi Krads, thanks for your help! Somehow I get the error when running rle(example.df$saccade): 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type atm. Didnt had that before. What I want is the script to take the last time and distract the first time where s in a sequence appeared, to indeed calculate the duration of it. Trying to fix my other problem atm

Comment: You must have used the code before my previous edit re:  adding stringsAsFactors = FALSE.  Try again with that and let me know also what form you would like the output in e.g. vector of durations or data.frame with duration & s/f adjacent?

Comment: allright that helps. However, where do you assign 'i' in the diff(c(1,i),1) ? because object i is not found. As an output, i would like your last suggestion! thanks alot for your time again!

Comment: that `i` should have been `index_of_changes`, now corrected.

Comment: Yes indeed! It is the solution to my problem! Funny to see two different ways, both working well. Thanks a lot to you and LAP for helping me out this fast! Amazing